# Really simple php array issue

Tags: php

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but it appears I'm having myself a brain fry trying to comprehend it..

```
$cards = array(range(1,52));
shuffle($cards);
echo $cards[0];
```

I get a array to string conversion error.

I've also tried a custom function to echo dependent on the input value and that isn't working either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating an array of arrays.  `range()` already returns an array:

```
$cards = range(1,52);
shuffle($cards);
echo $cards[0];
```

Comment: [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php): "Create an array containing a range of elements."

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function returns an array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), so the statement `$cards = array(range(1,52));` has set `$cards` to be an array with exactly one element - an array containing the range of values from 1 to 52.

Thus when you try to `echo $cards[0]`, you are trying to echo an element which is an array, which produces the error.

What you want to do is this:

```
$cards = range(1, 52);
shuffle($cards);
echo $cards[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it fully!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `array`, `range` returns an array:

```
$cards = range(1,52);
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my issue !

Answer (score 0):

Range already creates an array.  You have create an array with one element that contains the array.

```
$cards =range(1,52);
shuffle($cards);
echo $cards[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my issue !